# How can I define a relationship between GTFS' trips and calendar/calendar_dates tables?

Tags: google, general-transit-feed-specification

From [the Google GTFS reference guide](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference?hl=en#tripstxt), the '*Service_id*' field of '**trips.txt**' file is referenced from the **calendar.txt** or **calendar_dates.txt** file. I want to create a database for GTFS, so how I can add a foreign-key relationship here?

Comment: Anuraj, was I able to answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logically the `service_id` field should be defined as a foreign key in `trips`. However, this is made difficult by the fact it can reference a row in either `calendar` *or* `calendar_dates`. Normally foreign keys in a relational database define a relationship between exactly two tables, not three or more.

What I have done in the past is **simply skip defining this relationship**. It's not actually needed to run queries against the data, and if you trust (or have validated separately) the GTFS feed there's little value in having the DBMS enforce this additional constraint.

If you feel you *must* define a foreign-key relationship here, I'd suggest preprocessing the data you receive to convert the contents of `calendar` and `calendar_dates` to a form that can be used in this way. For instance, you might merge this data together into a single table and then use that as the foreign key's target.

Remember GTFS is intended only as a format for transmitting data, not as a means of storing it, so it's perfectly reasonable to use a different representation for your app internally if that better meets its needs.

For some examples of using GTFS calendar data in real queries, take a look at these questions on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/):

- [How do I use calendar exceptions to generate accurate schedules using GTFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24099529/473305)
- [How can I include in schedules today's departures after midnight using GTFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24984375/473305)